# I need to remove Visual Composer tags that have a specific attribute

Tags: php, attributes, tags, visual-composer

This is Visual Composer code for two tabs, first tab has a button, and second one a text block.

```
[vc_row][vc_column][vc_tta_tabs][vc_tta_section title="Tab 1" 
tab_id="1506352393593-04f5c1a6-5efc"][vc_btn][/vc_tta_section][vc_tta_section 
title="Tab 2" tab_id="1506352393594-b0508f81-4068"][vc_column_text]I am text 
block. Click edit button to change this text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, 
pulvinar dapibus leo.[/vc_column_text][/vc_tta_section][/vc_tta_tabs]
[/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

I need to remove tags and everything between them that have a specific attribute in them. For example I want to remove sections that have helper=true as an attribute: 
    vc_tta_section helper="true" bla bla /vc_tta_section

This is on server side and needs to be done using PHP. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: Use PHP's regex functions (`preg_match`, `preg_replace`...)

Comment: actually that works. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while($posts->have_posts()) {
      $postContent = get_the_content();
      //Remove html tags. and short code
      $postContent = strip_tags( do_shortcode( $postContent ) );
      //Remove visual composer tags [vc_column] etc
      $postContent = preg_replace( "/\[(\/*)?vc_(.*?)\]/", '', $postContent );
}
?>
```